# Kendo ComboBox AutoSelect if only one value is filtered

Tags: combobox, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo combobox which has almost 4 values. I want the value to be autoselected if only one value is filtered in combobox.
For example my combobox is having below values:
India
Australia
US
UK

If I type "In" in my combobox, onchange India should be selected automatically. Can someone please guide me how to implement this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for this:

```
var widget = $(".myComboBox").data("kendoComboBox");                 
if (widget.selectedIndex === -1 && widget.value()) {
  if (widget.dataSource.view().length > 0) {
       widget.select(0)  
  } else {
        widget.value("");                          
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "onFiltering" or "onDataBound" event. Check for length and use

```
$("#id").data("kendoDropDownList").select(0) syntax.
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion. Actually I am using Combobox, not the dropdown list